# How to show dependency of a plugin in Maven?

Tags: maven, plugins, dependencies

I want to see transitive dependencies of a mavenplugin, so I made clear project with only one plugin and without another artifact dependencies to see this plugin dependencies. So I write

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-xjc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <extensions>
                        <extension>org.apache.cxf.xjcplugins:cxf-xjc-dv:2.3.0</extension>
                    </extensions>
                </configuration>

            </plugin>

        </plugins>
</build>
...
```

and run

```
       mvn dependency:tree
```

and the output is :

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Sample project  2.0.3-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ delete ---
INFO] sample:test:jar:2.0.3-SNAPSHOT
INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
```

How to see org.apache.cxf dependency tree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best thing is to use the [maven-dependency-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/resolve-plugins-mojo.html) with the goal `resolve-plugins`. like this:

```
mvn dependency:resolve-plugins
```